# Parameter '...' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am using VS Code for my project, where I encountered this error. I checked other solutions like setting *"noImplicitAny: false"* but the problem - "*Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type*" & "*Parameter 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type*" persists. The TypeScript code is given below.

```
  getContacts()
  {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/contacts')
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

  //add contact method
  addContact (newContact)
  {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/contact', newContact, {headers:headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  //delete method
  deleteContact(id)
  {
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/contact/'+id)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: Why not annotate the function parameters yourself, like `id: number` or `id: string`?  Also, please consider modifying this code so as to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like The TypeScript Playground where the issue you're talking about is present and other issues are not. [Link](https://tsplay.dev/m02oOw)

Comment: What is the type of `this.http`? If I use the type `import {Http} from "@angular/http";` then I actually get errors on the `.map` because `http.get` etc. returns an `Observable<Request>`.  Your functions are expecting `Array<Request>` which feels like it can't be right.  Why is it an `array`?

Comment: As far as "Parameter 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type.", this is a totally expected and desired error.  You need to declare the type for the `id` argument. `deleteContact(id: string)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing `res =>` to `(res: any) =>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).